# Invariant relating to some operations on a 2 by 3 real matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $a,b,c,d,e,f \in \mathbb {R}$  with $a+b+c+d+e+f = 0$. Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\
e & f
\end{bmatrix}$.

Define $I(A)=\{a, b, c, d, e, f, a+b, a+d,a+f,c+b,c+d,c+f,e+b,e+d,e+f
\\ -a, -b, -c, -d, -e, -f, -a-b, -a-d,-a-f,-c-b,-c-d,-c-f,-e-b,-e-d,-e-f\}$.

Now define the following set
$F(A) $ for every $A $ defined as above:

$1) A \in F(A)$.

$2) \begin{bmatrix}a & b \\c & d \\e & f\end{bmatrix} \in F \Rightarrow 
\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\-b-e & -a-f \\-b-c & -a-d\end{bmatrix} \in F $.

$3) \begin{bmatrix}a & b \\c & d \\e & f\end{bmatrix} \in F \Rightarrow 
\begin{bmatrix}a+f & b+c \\-c & c+d \\e+f & -f\end{bmatrix} \in F $.

$4) \begin{bmatrix}a & b \\c & d \\e & f\end{bmatrix} \in F \Rightarrow 
\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\e & f \\c & d\end{bmatrix} \in F $.

Finally let $x,y,z,t,p,q \in \mathbb {R}$  with $x+y+z+t+p+q = 0$. Let $B = \begin{bmatrix}
x & y \\
z & t \\
p & q
\end{bmatrix}$.

Prove that $B \in F(A) $ if and only if $I(A) = I(B)$.

Some extra things.

Is there some clever way to check $I(A) = I(B)$?

Do the transformations in $2),3),4) $ remind you of any other thing in math?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Haven't found anything meaningful. Of course, the reverse proof is very easy as you just check that 2) 3), and 4) preserve the invariant, but other than that nothing.

Comment: Tried using matrix multiplication but didn't find anything.

Comment: Ohhhh I see, thank you.

Comment: (Reposted due to error.) Let the transformations in 2)-4) be denoted $T_2,T_3,T_4$. It looks like there's some nontrivial relations between these maps. Firstly, they're all involutions: $T_2^2=T_3^2=T_4^2=\text{id}$ (squared in the sense of composition). Additionally, it seems that $$(T_3T_2)^4=(T_4T_2)^2=(T_4 T_3)^6=\text{id}$$ if $a+b+c+d+e+f=0$ is enforced. That points to some fancy reflection group business but that's above my head...